# Memory Barrier Vs CAS

Tags: java, cpu-architecture, atomic, memory-barriers, compare-and-swap

I find that CAS will flush all CPU write cache to main memory。 Is this similar to memory barrier？

If this is true, does this mean CAS can make java Happens-Before work?

For answer：

The CAS is CPU instruction.
The barrier is a StoreLoad barrier because what I care about is will the data are written before CAS can be read after CAS.

More Detail:
I have this question because I am writing a fork-join built in Java. The implementation is like this

```
{
    //initialize result container
    Objcet[] result = new Object[];
    //worker finish state count
    AtomicInteger state = new AtomicInteger(result.size);
}

//worker thread i
{
  result[i] = new Object();
  //this is a CAS operation
  state.getAndDecrement(); 

  if(state.get() == 0){
     //do something useing result array
  }
}
```

I want to know can (do something using result array) part see all result element which is written by other worker thread.

Comment: Is `c++` tag relevant in your question?

Comment: That CAS instruction are you talking about.  Be specific.  (And how are you causing this CAS instruction to be used?)   Note that your example is NOT showing an instruction.  It is showing a Java method call to a method whose *happens before* semantics are specified ... making this discussion of CAS and memory barriers moot.

Comment: I do not know that this java method have happens before semantic.  I know that read and write of a volatile varible have happens before semantics. But here is a CAS for a volatile varible.

Comment: Can you specific how it guarantee happens before semantics?

Comment: It is all specified in the javadocs.  I have updated my answer with the relevant text and link.

Comment: On 64-bit ARM, there are different CAS instructions, with different memory ordering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find that CAS will flush all cpu write cache to main memory。 Is this similar to memory barrier？

1. It depends on what you mean by CAS.  (A specific hardware instruction?  An implementation strategy used in the implementation of some Java class?)
2. It depends on what kind of memory barrier you are talking about.  There are a number of different kinds ...
3. It is not necessarily true that a CAS *instruction* flushes *all* dirty cache lines.  It depends on how a particular instruction set / hardware implements the CAS instruction.

It is unclear what you mean by "make *happens-before* work".  Certainly, under some circumstance a CAS instruction would provide the necessary memory coherency properties for a specific *happens-before* relationship.  But not necessarily all relationships.  It would depend on how the CAS instruction is implemented by the hardware, and how it was used in the (native) code.

To be honest, **unless you are actually writing a Java native code compiler**, you would do better to not try to understanding the intricacies of what a JIT compiler does to implement the Java Memory Model; e.g. whether and how it uses CAS instructions.  Instead, just do the *happens before* analysis to figure out if visibility of updates is guaranteed (by the JLS) for the accesses you are concerned about.  IMO, you can safely assume<sup>1</sup> that the JIT compilers emit native code that behaves according to the requirements of the [Java Memory Model specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

<sup>1 - If not, the chances are high that other Java developers will already have noticed the problem and submitted bug reports.  Assuming that the necessary supporting evidence is included, such reports would be addressed urgently.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out from your recent updates and comments that your actual question is about the behavior of `AtomicInteger` operations.

The memory semantics of the atomic types are specified in the package [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) for `java.util.concurrent.atomic` as follows:

> The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles, as stated in The Java Language Specification (17.4 Memory Model):
>
> - `get` has the memory effects of reading a volatile variable.
> - `set` has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable.
> - `lazySet` has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable except that it permits reorderings with subsequent (but not previous) memory actions that do not themselves impose reordering constraints with ordinary non-volatile writes. Among other usage contexts, lazySet may apply when nulling out, for the sake of garbage collection, a reference that is never accessed again.
> - `weakCompareAndSet` atomically reads and conditionally writes a variable but does not create any happens-before orderings, so provides no guarantees with respect to previous or subsequent reads and writes of any variables other than the target of the weakCompareAndSet.
> - `compareAndSet` and all other read-and-update operations such as `getAndIncrement` have the memory effects of both reading and writing volatile variables.

As you can see, operations on Atomic types are specified to have memory semantics that are equivalent volatile variables.  This should be sufficient to reason about your use of Java atomic types ... without resorting to dubious analogies with CAS instructions and memory barriers.

---

Your example is incomplete and it is difficult to understand what it is trying to do.  Therefore, I can't comment on its correctness.   However, you should be able to analyze it yourself using *happens-before* logic, etc.

Comment: I add some detail in question. I want to know if CAS can make the result array be seen in final work thread.

Answer (score 2):

> I find that CAS will flush all CPU write cache to main memory。
> Is this similar to memory barrier？

A CAS in Java on the X86 is implemented using a lock prefix and then it depends on the type of CAS what kind of instruction is actually being used; but that isn't that relevant for this discussion. A locked instruction effectively is a full barrier; so it includes all 4 fences: LoadLoad/LoadStore/StoreLoad/StoreStore. Since the X86 provides all but StoreLoad due to TSO, only the StoreLoad needs to be added; just as with a volatile write.

A StoreLoad doesn't force changes to be written to main memory; it only forces the CPU to wait executing loads till the store buffer has been be drained to the L1d. However, with MESI (Intel) based cache coherence protocols, it can happen that a cache-line that is in MODIFIED state on a different CPU, needs to be flushed to main memory before it can be returned as EXCLUSIVE. With MOESI (AMD) based cache coherence protocols, this is not an issue. If the cache-line is already in MODIFIED,EXCLUSIVE state on the core doing the StoreLoad, StoreLoad doesn't cause the cache line to be flushed to main memory. The cache is the source of truth.

> > If this is true, does this mean CAS can make java Happens-Before work?

From a memory model perspective, a successful CAS in java is nothing else than a volatile read followed by a volatile write. So there is a happens before relation between a volatile write of some field on some object instance and a subsequent volatile read on the same field on the same object instance.

Since you are working with Java, I would focus on the Java Memory Model and not too much on how it is implemented in the hardware. The JMM is allowing for executions that can't be explained based purely by thinking in fences.

Regarding your example:

```
result[i] = new Object();
//this is a CAS operation
state.getAndDecrement(); 

if(state.get() == 0){
   //do something using result array
}
```

I'm not sure what the intended logic is. In your example, multiple threads at the same time could see that the state is 0, so all could start to do something with the array. If this behavior is undesirable, then this is caused by a race condition. I would use something like this:

```
result[i] = new Object();
//this is a CAS operation
int s = state.getAndDecrement(); 

if(s == 0){
   //do something using result array

}
```

Now the other question is if there is a data race on the array content. There is a happens-before edge between the write to the array content and the write to 'state' (program order rule). There is a happens before edge between the write of the state and the read (volatile variable rule) and there is a happens before relation between the read of the state and the read of the array content (program order rule). So there is a happens before edge between writing to the array and reading its content in this particular example due to the transitive nature of the happens-before relation.

Personally I would not to try too be too smart and use something less array prone like an AtomicReferenceArray; then at least you don't need to worry about missing happens before edge between the write of the array and the read.

Comment: It's my fault,  I actually use the `decrementAndGet` method and use the return value directly.  The code in question is not the copy of my real code. Your answer is clear, Thanks a lot!